# Помогите разобраться как получить строки child в Expandable Recycler View

Tags: android, массивы, recyclerview, adapter, android-alertdialog

Переделываю `Expandable Recycler View`. Все пишу вроде бы правильно и не могу понять в чем у меня ошибка. Я передаю массив строк с `RecyclerView` в `AlertDialog` но приложение падает так как нет позиции отвечающей за эти строку.

**Помогите определить позицию для строки**
Вот код адаптера

```
public class AnalysisAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<BigViewHolder, AnalysisAdapter.AnalysisViewHolder> {

    private TextView text_rv;
    private ImageView arrow;
    Context c;

    public AnalysisAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
        super(groups);
    }
    public class AnalysisViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {
        HtmlTextView textView;
        FrameLayout frame;
        public AnalysisViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_rc);
            frame = itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public BigViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expandable_rv,parent,false);
        return new BigViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public AnalysisViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expandable_rc,parent,false);
        return new AnalysisViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(AnalysisViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
        final Analysys analysys = (Analysys) group.getItems().get(childIndex);
        holder.textView.setHtml(analysys.name);
        holder.frame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder aa = new AlertDialog.Builder((Activity) c);
                    aa.setTitle(analysys.name);//тут определить позицию
                    aa.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(analysys.analysis)); //и тут определить позицию
                    aa.setNegativeButton(c.getString(R.string.back), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindGroupViewHolder(BigViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
        final Big big = (Big) group;
        holder.bind(big);
    }
}
```

Стек:

```
2019-08-31 15:13:30.480 8682-8682/com.vn.iambulance.prototype_20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vn.iambulance.prototype_20, PID: 8682
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:115)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:313)
        at com.vn.iambulance.prototype_20.adapter_analysis.AnalysisAdapter$1.onClick(AnalysisAdapter.java:61)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7076)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

***Помогите хочу сегодня уже опубликовать обновление но не могу решить эту проблему уже пару дней.***

Comment: ошибка точно связана с текущей проблемой? так как текст самой ошибки связан вообще не со списком насколько я могу судить, но я могу ошибаться

Comment: Ошибка связана с тем что RecyclerView Adapter не понимает от какой позиции брать строки для AlertDialog. Потому что не указана позиция. Если вы знаете в чем ошибка то помогите её исправить.

Comment: В других адаптерах эта проблема не возникает так как я указываю позицию строки которую нужно отобразить.

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference` эти строки говорят о том что у вас не находится тема, и поэтому приложение падает, либо вы не тот лог прикрепили, и в последнем комментарии вы сказали что в других адаптерах ошибка не возникает так как вы указываете позицию, тогда почему нельзя попробовать решить проблему подобным образом и здесь?)

Comment: В том той проблема что я не знаю как прикрепить позицию к строкам так как этот адаптер значительно отличается от простого адаптера. В строке `final Analysys analysys = (Analysys) group.getItems().get(childIndex);` вроде бы определяется позиция но кажется не так как нада.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko смотрел я ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288555/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-content-res-resourcestheme-android-co) но как определить getActivity(); я не знаю не подскажете?

Comment: вам нужно в конструктор адаптера передать `context` и оттуда брать уже тему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка, а именно строка:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
```

говорит о том что вы не можете получить тему. Если проблема с получением темы в адаптере, то нужно пересмотреть как вы передаете контекст (`context`) в адаптер и уже при наличии контекста ваша проблема решится.